# How to display a base64 image within a UIImageView Using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking

i am using base64 images it show in imageview using below code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:prodDetCompl.AttPath];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
cell.imageView.image = ret;
```

but i need use AFNetworking for loading the image not succeeded

```
[imageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleimages.jpeg"]]
```

how to do that

thanks

Comment: Is there anything at `AFNetworking` license preventing you from making the changes ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what is not working for you, but should you not be doing something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:prodDetCompl.AttPath];
[imageview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleimages.jpeg"]]
```

you should ensure, of course, that a "sample images.jpeg" image is available in your bundle resources to be used as a placeholder image.

Comment: are you sure that the placeholder image is bundled with your app?